# Is there anything bsearch for strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I know this question been asked in some form before, but I'm specifically looking to use this for Strings, and for something faster than .include?.

I want to use it on an ordered list of strings (alphabetical).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the closest (in one direction)

```
array = ["aardvark", "amazon", "binary", "zelda"]
array.bsearch { |s| s >= "binary" }
# => "binary"
array.bsearch { |s| s >= "binaries" }
# => "binary"
```

To find exact match,

```
array.bsearch { |s| "binary" <=> s }
# => "binary"
array.bsearch { |s| "binaries" <=> s }
# => nil
```

It is an `Array` functionality, nothing to do with strings in particular; you can `bsearch` for anything that you can implement a comparator for, as long as the array is sorted accordingly.

Comment: If I do array.bsearch { |s| s <=> "amazon" } , why do i get => nil ?

Comment: same with other elements in the array besides "binary"

Comment: Because I am an idiot, and got `"binary"` working by pure luck. I will edit and correct... I had the condition reversed (`s <=> "binary"`), which you'd use if the array was reverse-sorted. Since "binary" is in the middle, `bsearch` started from it and got it right. Pure dumb luck.